# GraphQL Resolver for Relations

Tags: mongodb, graphql, return-value, relation, mutation

I would like to write a mutation, which when creating a tracker, enters the tracker model ID and the user ID for the respective tracker model and the user. My question relates to the return statement in the Resolve function: how can I execute both functions directly after each other, so that it´s being written in both collections?

Here is my mutation. As it is currently written, only the second variable is executed, in this case only "tm".

```js
createTracker: {
      type: TrackerType,
      args: {
        trackerModelID: {type: GraphQLID },
        userId: {type: GraphQLID },
        access_token: {type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parent, args){
        let tracker = new Tracker({
          trackerModelID: args.trackerModelID,
          userId: args.userId,
          access_token: args.access_token,
        });
        tracker.save();
        let tm = TrackerModel.updateOne({ _id: args.trackerModelID }, { $push: { trackerIds: tracker._id } });
        let us = User.updateOne({ _id: args.userId }, { $push: { trackerIds: tracker._id } });
        return us && tm
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I tried all these ways, but it did´nt work.

But now,  I found the answer by myself, this works:

```js
tracker.save();
return User.updateOne({ _id: args.userId }, { $push: { trackerIds: tracker._id } }).then(() =>{
 return TrackerModel.updateOne({ _id: args.trackerModelID }, { $push: { trackerIds: tracker._id } });
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try;

1) remove `return us && tm`

2) declare array: `var results = [us , tm];`

3) return array: `return results`